# Trying to launch application through python

Tags: python

I am trying to launch one application through python. I am having problem with this can any give me a solution?

```
path1= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\XYZ\\NX2\\RT900"

ver="7.50 Internal Release"

path2="bin\\Rt900.exe"

path3=os.path.join(path1,ver)

path4=os.path.join(path3,path2)

App.open("path4")
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in above statement?

Answer (score 2):

you should join `path1` with `path2` not `ver`

```
path3 = os.path.join(path1, path2)
```

also you are doing `path4=os.path.join(path3,path4)` here `path4` is used before assignment

Answer (score 1):

As avasal has mentioned you should join paths correctly:

```
path3 = os.path.join(path1, path2)
```

It also looks like you need to open the path like so:

```
App.open(path3)
```

Note the lack of quotation marks in the last line.

Edit:

Seeing you keep changing the code in your question I have noted another error in your code:

```
path4=os.path.join(path3,path4)
```

This line will always file you are trying to join with a variable that doesn't even exist yet. A variable can't reference itself when it is being assigned for the first time. In this case you are doing `os.path.join(path3, path4)` but `path4` doesn't even exist yet!

Comment: Hi... I had skipped some lines of code while copying.. So, i edited my question again.. Thanks for the solution. I was having problem with App.open(path3) line of code.